# Minimal immersion

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $N$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold immersed in an $l$-dimensional manifold $L$ by immersion $\iota: N\to L$. And let $\iota$ be minimal immersion. On the other hand, let $\phi: M\to N$ be totally geodesic immersion from an $m$-dimensional manifold $M$ to $N$. Is then $f:M\to L$ minimal immersion? I can not find a way to prove that, or to prove that $f$ is not minimal.

Comment: Is $f=\iota\circ\phi$?

Comment: I don't think so, take any nonflat minimal surface $N$ in $L=\mathbb R^3$ and $M$ is a geodesic in $N$. $M$ might not be a straight line (thus not minimal in $\mathbb R^3$).